# PHP changes not showing up until Composer Update

Tags: php, magento2, development-environment

I'm working on a cronjob that will delete products by last date updated.

I'm seeing very strange Magento 2 behavior - the PHP file changes are not showing up until I update the repository and then run **composer update**.

The store is in **Development mode**. Running via Docker-compose.

During development on **other plugins** as soon as I do:

```
rm -rf var/generation var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend generated/code
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```

The file changes show up and sometimes even without these commands.

But, with this plugin the changes do not show up until I fully push changes to repository and then run **composer update** with all the other commands.

Is there some kind of caching for cron job classes that I don't know about?

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

Here is my folder structure:

```
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\Cron\DeleteOldProducts.php
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\etc\config.xml
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\etc\crontab.xml
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\etc\module.xml
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\composer.json
src\vendor\company\deleteoldproducts\registration.php
```

The DeleteOldProducts.php is being used by the cron job, but uses an old version of it. I try to make changes to it, re-run the commands mentioned above, but cronjob still uses old version of the file. This is not normal.

Here is the php file:

```
<?php

namespace Company\DeleteOldProducts\Cron;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class DeleteOldProducts
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_productRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $_productRepositoryInterface,
        CollectionFactory $_productCollectionFactory
   ) {
       $this->_productRepositoryInterface = $_productRepositoryInterface;
       $this->_productCollectionFactory = $_productCollectionFactory;
   }

    public function execute()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/DELETE-OLD-PRODUCTS.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('---DELETING IS HAPPENING---');

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(10);

        $logger->info("COLLECTION?11111111");

        foreach($collection as $product)
        {
            $logger->info('PRODUCT ID' . $product->getId());
        }

        $logger->info("COLLECTION?222222222");

        $logger->info('---DELETING IS HAPPENING---');
        $logger->info('                           ');
        $logger->info('                           ');
   
        return $this;

    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The only thing I've seen where changes to PHP files are not adhered to is OPcache. either restarting the httpd or manual invocation via https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php (Also, I have never used magento, so there may be something I don't understand)

Comment: @Scuzzy, thanks! I have tried this already, but did not work. Opcache was off at the moment. My only other guess is maybe when I went from /app/code to /vendor/company there's some confusion by Magento. I'll try renaming the module tomorrow to see if it helps. This is definitely the strangest behavior I've seen.

Comment: @Scuzzy that setting is commented out. opcache.save_comments is also commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - I had naming conflicts between the the plugin I was developing and the one in the composer

One was "deleteoldproducts" and the one in composer was "module-deleteoldproducts".

Should have deleted the original folder after I pushed it to repository.